# JQuery select by inner text

Tags: jquery

I am doing a project with fullcalendar and I need to be able to select an element based on the day number.  Here is a sample of the element I need to select:

```
<div class=​"fc-day-number">​1​</div>​
```

Here is the javascript I have written:

```
$("div.fc-day-number:contains(" + day + ")").parent().parent().css({ 'background-color': 'Green' });
```

This will grab all the divs whose inner text contains the day variable, problem is if day==1 then it also selects 11,12,13,21,31,etc.  How do I write a JQuery selector that will grab the divs with class "fc-day-number" and whose inner text is exactly equal to day?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write your own `filter` function:

```
$("div.fc-day-number").filter(function (){
    return $(this).text() == day;
}).parent().parent().css({ 'background-color': 'Green' });
```

Comment: I would probably add $(this).text().toLowerCase() === day;

Comment: @Kris Why?  The OP is just using numbers so case shouldn't matter.  I also used the double equals because I figured day would be numeric while `text()` would be a string.

Comment: Oh, I thought it could be just any text/string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div.fc-day-number").each(function (){
    if($(this).text()==day)
    {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'Green' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.expr[":"].text = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg)
{
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toLowerCase() == arg;
    };
});
```

This code will add the new pseudoselector which will filter elements the internal text which isn't equal to arg. For you example use here so:

```
$("div.fc-day-number:text(" + day + ")").parent().parent().css({ 'background-color': 'Green' });
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.