# Get all elements by inner text

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with a problem:
I want to search for a string in a html document. So far I tried with window.find(..) method, but I can't get back the node of the found elements. Just for example i can highlight all the matching texts.
But I want to put all the nodes in an array, and I can't find a method, which can return me the node of the selected text.
The following code only highlights the matching texts, I want to get the (parent) node of it.

```
function doSearchAdam(text) {
if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
    while (window.find(text)) {
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
} else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    while (textRange.findText(text)) {
        textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
        textRange.collapse(false);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks guys!
Adam

Comment: Can you use jquery? then you can do similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486282/jquery-select-by-inner-text

Comment: Yeah thanks! Very useful! Here is the code, in case somebody's wondering about the solution:
'$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#findButton").click(function() {
  myFunction();
 });
});

function myFunction() {
 var matchedPages = new Array();
 $(".Page").filter(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf($("#findText").val()) >= 0) {//$("#findText").value()
   console.log($(this));
   matchedPages.push($(this));
  }
 });
 console.log(matchedPages);
 console.log(matchedPages[1].attr("id"));
}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placed the code from your comment above into code tags for better readability.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#findButton").click(function() { 
        myFunction(); 
    }); 
});

function myFunction() { 
    var matchedPages = new Array(); 
    $(".Page").filter(function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf($("#findText").val()) >= 0) {
            //$("#findText").value() console.log($(this)); 
            matchedPages.push($(this)); 
        } 
    }); 
    console.log(matchedPages);
    console.log(matchedPages[1].attr("id")); 
}
```