# How do I change :contains to work on the exact string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that sets a class depending on a textstring. However I cant quite make it to work, it sets all the three options to the second class. How do I change contains to something like Equals instead?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('span.conditionHilite:contains("Approved Selection ONE")').length){
$(".productbox .item .right").before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner">    </span>' );
}
else if ($('span.conditionHilite:contains("Approved Selection")').length){
$(".productbox .item .right").before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner2">  </span>' );
}
else if ($('span.conditionHilite:contains("Approved Selection Budget")').length){
$(".productbox .item .right").before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner3"></span>' );
}
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery select by inner text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486282/jquery-select-by-inner-text)

Comment: `$.trim()` check with `$('span.conditionHilite:contains($.trim($('span.conditionHilite.text()))')`

Comment: May be your text contains white spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.conditionHilite').each(function(){
   var productBoxClass;

   if($(this).text() == 'Approved Selection ONE')
   {
      productBoxClass = 'myAwesomeBanner';
   }
   else if($(this).text() == 'Approved Selection')
   {
      productBoxClass = 'myAwesomeBanner2';
   }
   else if($(this).text() == 'Approved Selection Budget')
   {
      productBoxClass = 'myAwesomeBanner3';
   }

   if(productBoxClass)
   {
       $(".productbox .item .right").before( '<span class="' + productBoxClass + '"></span>' );
   } 
});
```

**Explanation:**

Loop through all of the relevant `span` elements, if any meet the text conditions, set the new class to be used in creating the new `span` and use this class at the end to create your `span`.

**Alternative Approach**

To keep in-line with the idea of counting (i.e. use of `length`) on matching elements, you could've used jQuery filter:

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Which would return a list of elements, just have you have with the use of `contains`.